# How to Handle the UiTableviewCell textfields?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield

i have custom tableview cell in custom cell i am taking the two textfield(First name,Age).My problem is how to handle the these textfields.if user not fill these these details we show the alert, per suppose user fill the details how to fetch the data.
Bellow is my tableview custom cell image.
[image]

Comment: Need more information

Comment: This is ticket booking app, user select ticket no of ticket ,based on tickets cell will be increase.here use not fill the details we need to show the alert and user fill the details how to get the user information.

Comment: Set tag for the textfields and get the value from the textfields on a button click event.

Comment: textfields are not constant some times it's coming 1/2/4 that is based on user booking tickets that time how to give the tags

Comment: In cellForRowAtIndexPath method set tag for the textfields like nameTextfield.tag = indexPath.row + 100 ageTextfield.tag = indexPath.row + 200

Comment: can you post some code please.

Comment: Pls give your cellForRowAtIndexPath method code here.

Comment: i dont't have any idea how to this, in cellForRowAtIndexPath i am not write any code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130279/discussion-between-rajeshkumar-r-and-siva-sankar).

Comment: Create a class for your custom cell and create outlets for the textfields. Then set tag for the textfields in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. And get the textfield values anywhere using these tags.

Comment: can you post sample code then i can understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add all textfields to `NSMutableArray` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
       [mutableArrary addObject:cell.yourTextField];
       return cell;
}
```

after that in your button action do like this:

```
-(IBAction)buttonAction:(id)sender{
  for (UITextField*textField in mutableArray){
  NSLog(@"%@",textField.text);
    }
}
```

Check there if any text is coming as nil then you can show alert like fill all details.

Comment: Worked like charm