# Store table view data in array on button click - Objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uitableview, loops

I have a `UITableView` with each cell having text fields. I want to get the text written in those text field in an `NSMutableArray`

Currently am doing this on button click -

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
   _optionTextArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

}

- (IBAction)saveClicked:(UIButton *)sender {

    editVotingOptionCell *cell = [_tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

    for (int i=0; i<_optionArray.count; i++) {
        [_optionTextArray addObject:cell.tfOption.text];
    }
}
```

But every time empty string is getting stored.

Comment: all cells are visible ??

Comment: are you allocating the memory of your `_optionTextArray`, add some additional code

Comment: YES  they all are visible @Sh_Khan

Comment: check my edited question @Anbu.karthik

Comment: Wouldn't you already need to have it in an array in the first place?

Comment: You can check my answer here which is exactly works in your case https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41073114/how-to-handle-the-uitableviewcell-textfields/41075570#41075570

Comment: Where are the text values which were used to set in your text field? Why didn't you use that source of text instead of reading them back from the TableView's cell?

Answer (score 0):

```
@interface MyCell: UITableViewCell {
    @property(strong) UITextField *textField;
}
```

Suppose you have a cell with class `MyCell` when your button is tap first get the number of rows in section. Let you have a default section which is `0` so get the number of rows for section zero after this iterate through a loop and get cell at every indexPath and get the text from that indexPath and check whether text is empty or not and finally insert it into an Array.
Bellow is the sample code of button click.

```
    NSInteger numberOfRows = [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0]
    NSMutableArray *allTexts = [NSMutableArray new];
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i< numberOfRows; i++) {
         NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
         MyCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        if (cell.textField.text != nil) {
            [allText addObject:cell.textField.text];
        }

}
```

Comment: @HappilyHemu check this out.

Comment: Do not forget to check the IBOutlet of your TextField which should be connected in order to get data from textField.

Comment: This is working fine. But the issue is like if am having 6 cell then only 5 values get added. The first loop goes into nil

Comment: You have to check why is that so because there must an issue on your side which is causing this to happen.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
(IBAction)saveClicked:(UIButton *)sender {

     for (int i=0; i<_optionArray.count; i++) {

        editVotingOptionCell *cell = [_tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]];
        if (cell != nil) {
          [_optionTextArray addObject:cell.tfOption.text];
        }
        else {
          NSLog(@"nil cell")
        }

    }
}
```

//

```
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath { 
   editVotingOptionCell*cell = ///
   cell.tfOption.delegate = self;
   cell.tfOption.tag = indexPath.row;
   return cell;
}
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
   _optionTextArray[textField.tag] = textField.text 
}
```

//

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,UITextFieldDelegate>
```

**Note:** pre-init the array `_optionTextArray` with default values

Comment: its crashing the app with he following error : - Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'

Comment: Which means `cell.tfOption.text` is nil value now

Comment: this can only occur if a cell isn't visible

Comment: i guess my all cell are visible. Because using my code the app doesn't crash. Just empty string values are added into array. I need to get the value in text field instead to empty strings

Comment: try edit but note it will not count unvisible cells , your code uses **dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier** which isn't the case here

Comment: its ok my all cell are visible. Want a way to get the values in text field

Comment: the problem with table views is dequeuing consider using scrollView as saving in your case needs some advanced way of noticing endEditing of textfeild and save to it's corresponding position in array using tag that pre-setted inside cellForRowAt to indexPath.row if you can accomplish this then go on

Answer (score 0):

If all cells are visible, as you said, you can do it like here:

```
- (IBAction)saveClicked:(UIButton *)sender {
    for (int i=0; i < _tableView.visibleCells.count; i++) {
       editVotingOptionCell *cell = self.tableView.visibleCells[i];
       [_optionTextArray addObject: cell.tfOption.text];
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

This method usable only if all your cells visible.

Because of reusing you can't get textField in the binding to concrete cell. Table view reuse cells.

So advice that you can see below that with cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath is not good idea because of table view policy.

If you want to get all texts from cells you should save it in array in other place, not in table view cells. For example, you can save text from text field in UITextFieldDelegate method after text field update.

Comment: this code give following error - Property 'tfOption' not found on object of type '__kindof UITableViewCell *'

Comment: Updated, try now pls

Comment: this won't count all cells

Comment: If all cells are visible - it's the same, otherwise there are some problems because of cell reusing in tableview

Comment: how to count all cell then? @AntonRodzik

Answer (score 0):

I think it’s better to get data from the **tableView’s dataSource array** rather than from cells.

So everytime textField’s text changed you shoule store it’s value,I had written a demo for you:

This is **MyCell.h** code:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

typedef void(^TextFieldValueChangedBlock)(NSString *text);

@interface MyCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic, copy) TextFieldValueChangedBlock textFieldValueChangedBlock;

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *textFieldValue;

@end
```

This is **MyCell.m** code:

```
#import "MyCell.h"

@interface MyCell ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) UITextField *myTextField;

@end

@implementation MyCell 

- (instancetype)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    if (self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier]) {
        self.myTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 40)];
        [self.contentView addSubview:self.myTextField];
        [self.myTextField addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)textFieldChanged:(UITextField *)textField {
    if (self.textFieldValueChangedBlock) {
        self.textFieldValueChangedBlock(textField.text);
    }
}

- (void)setTextFieldValue:(NSString *)textFieldValue {
    self.myTextField.text = textFieldValue;
}

@end
```

At last this is **ViewController.m** code:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "MyCell.h"

@interface ViewController () <UITableViewDataSource>

@property (nonatomic, strong) UITableView *tableView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *dataArray;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *stringArray;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.dataArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        [self.dataArray addObject:@"text"];
    }

    self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    [self.view addSubview:self.tableView];
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
}

- (void)saveClicked:(UIButton *)sender {
    self.stringArray = self.dataArray.mutableCopy;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.dataArray.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *cellReuseID = @"cell";
    MyCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellReuseID];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[MyCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellReuseID];
    }
    cell.textFieldValue = self.dataArray[indexPath.row];
    // textField value change,store value
    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf= self;
    cell.textFieldValueChangedBlock = ^(NSString *text) {
        __strong typeof(self) strongSelf = weakSelf;
        [strongSelf.dataArray replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:text];
    };
    return cell;
}

@end
```